# $.get within a .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Not really sure where I'm going wrong with this one. I have a button element that when clicked, I want the following script below to be triggered. No issues seemingly in Chrome when I click the button but the file isn't fetched.

Am I missing something silly in my .click?

```
  <script>
        $( "button" ).click(function() {
            $.get("testimg.php", function() {
                alert("Success!");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: make sure that the button isn't actually triggering the browser to navigate away from the current page, which'd abort any JS in-progress.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a failure callback as well to see if there are any error messages?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Did you remember to include jQuery? :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems right. You need to make sure 2 things:

1. `testimg.php` (with m) file exists in the same directory.
2. The `<button>` is in the DOM when the script runs. I recommend using `$(document).ready()` event:

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $( "button" ).click(function() {
               $.get("testimg.php", function() {
                   alert("Success!");
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLqgu/1/)

Comment: @AreYouSure did it resolve your question or is there still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Worth making it a `jQuery.ajax` call so you can trace errors.

```
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "testimg.php",
      success: function () {
         alert("Success!");
      },
      error: function(x,y,z) {
        alert(z);
      }
    });
  });
});
```